# How can this "click to enlarge image" function for multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I can't get this effect to work on multiple images. JavaScript is calling for the `getElementById` it seems to only work for a single image,
I've tried to change it to `getElementByClassName` (and also the HTML and CSS) but then the function stops working, how can I get this effect on multiple images/ divs?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;

  };

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };


};
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

#myImg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #FFD270;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myImg {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .45s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myndir-a4" data-title="">
  <img id="myImg" src="..\01.jpg" alt="this works fine">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <img id="img01" class="modal-content" src="..\01.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="myndir-a4" data-title="">
  <img id="myImg" src="..\02.jpg" alt="nothing happens">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <img id="img01" class="modal-content" src="..\02.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to give a unique ID and get them by unique ID.
ID should be unique, instead of id try to use class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is delegation

Note

- changed display: none to hidden on the tag and
- changed most IDs to class or removed them since they are no longer needed due to relative addressing

It would even be possible to have just one modal

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches(".myImg") && !tgt.matches(".close")) return; // not the image or close
    const parent = tgt.closest("div.myndir-a4");
    const modal = parent.querySelector('.modal');
    if (tgt.matches(".close")) {
      modal.hidden = true;
      return;
    }
    const modalImg = parent.querySelector("img.modal-content");
    const captionText = parent.querySelector(".caption");
    modal.hidden = false;
    modalImg.src = tgt.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = tgt.alt;
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.myImg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #FFD270;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.myImg {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .45s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="myndir-a4" data-title="">
    <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=image1" alt="this works fine">
    <div class="modal" hidden>
      <span class="close">X</span>
      <img class="modal-content" src="" alt="">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="myndir-a4" data-title="">
    <img class="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=image2" alt="This ALSO works now">
    <div class="modal" hidden>
      <span class="close">X</span>
      <img class="modal-content" src="" alt="">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that the image starts "already clicked on" and zoomed in, with no way to close it/ minimize it, the code snippet doesn't work for me at least

Comment: Please make sure you look at my CSS too. Does it not work for your here in the snippet?

Comment: unfortunately no, the snippet doesn't work for me,
when I run it I see the "this works fine"and"this ALSO works now" for a split second then, everything white and nothing to click on

Comment: Here at SO??? In what browser on what platform?

Comment: Reload the answer to see what I get in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: It worked fine after disabling Ad-blocker!
Strange that it should target something in a code snippet,
Thank you mplungjan, fixed!